# Where can one meet other Travel.SE members?

Tags: discussion, community

I've been fortunate to meet other members on the site in Vancouver, Montreal and NYC, and I know other meetups have happened.  I wondered if perhaps a community-wiki type list by continent and city for anyone who  would be keen to meet for a coffee would be a useful idea?  You may be passing through a city and have no idea user X lives there, who could show you around or give you a great tip.

I thought I'd create an answer and people can edit the answer, rather than have a thousand teeny unordered answers.

As for contacting, I guess an @tag is handy, but the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) is another good go to place to organise.

Comment: Would we not be better off more widely publicising the [Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/118962814909394/)?

Comment: @Gagravarr I wondered about that, but there's no easy way I know of to have a big note in there to show where everyone is?

Comment: Is there any way to merge/share this wiki answer with expat.se -- would seem like there might useful overlap there if the idea is meeting other people, particularly since ex-pat (if they're interested) are often a pretty good resource for visitors.

Comment: @SpaceDog not really, unfortunately. You could post a meta post there with a link to the travel one, which would potentially get some traction and some more connections across the two sites.

Comment: @Gagravarr fascinating. Didn't even know there was a Facebook group till I just saw your comment. Been using travel.se for years now... !

Comment: Another option might be to consider adding TripIt IDs (I've added mine). I find this a pretty good way to find when/where colleagues are going. (Personally, I use TripIt Pro too for a lot of my business travel, but that's getting off topic...)

Answer (score 18):

## **Africa**

## ...
**Asia**

Hong Kong: [uncovery](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3778)

India:

- Bangalore: [Prashanth](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1883/prashanth), [Saurav](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/40391/sinstein), [Gagravarr](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26/gagravarr) *(a few times a year)*
- Kerala & Tamilnadu  [Sagar V](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/57836/sagar-v)

Japan: [Aditya Somani](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12160), often also [uncovery](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3778)

Philippines:

- Manila: [SpaceDog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3119/spacedog)

Singapore: [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat)

South Korea: [revi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/47344/revi)

Sri Lanka:
[AyeshK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11736/ayesh-k)

Taiwan:

- Kenting: [image: ht] [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140)

## **Europe**

Azerbaijan

- Baku: [gdrt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/37602/gdrt)

Bulgaria

- Sofia: [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), motoDrizzt

Liechtenstein

- RoflcoptrException

Netherlands

- Amsterdam: [Flimzy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/444/flimzy)
- Near Amsterdam: [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)
- Delft (30 min south of Amsterdam): [Owen Versteeg](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43516/owen-versteeg)

Germany

- Hamburg: [ThorstenS](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/7442/thorsten-s)
- Frankfurt Rhine-Main: [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow) ([My TripIt](https://www.tripit.com/people/dirty.flow#/profile/upcoming-trips))
- Berlin [graup](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4210/graup)

Finland

- Helsinki: [downhand](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/24306/downhand)

France

- Anywhere: [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano)
- Paris: [A.A.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/33096/a-a)
- Strasbourg: [rugdealer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40163/rugdealer)

Ireland

- Dublin: [Richard](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/30440/richard)

Italy

- North west area: [Geeo](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2523/geeo), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)

Russia

- St. Petersburg, Moscow: [VMAtm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19/vmatm)

Spain

- A Coruña (Galicia): [Andión](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/57082/andi%C3%B3n)

Sweden

- Stockholm : [Johan Gronberg](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/35892/johan-gronberg)

Switzerland

- RoflcoptrException
- Zurich: [Crazydre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/39782/crazydre?tab=profile)

UK

- Edinburgh: [RoryAlsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)
- London: [Ankur Banerjee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/108/ankur-banerjee), [andrewferrier](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2555/andrew-ferrier) [[TripIt](https://www.tripit.com/people/andrewf)]
- Near London (willing to meet in London):

  - Surrey (around Guildford) - [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g)
  - Surrey (near Gatwick) [zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
  - Oxford - [Gagravarr](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26/gagravarr)
  - Basingstoke - [Muzer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/33051/muzer)
- Lancaster (Near Lake District): [Skifans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30717/skifans)
- Manchester (anywhere in Greater Manchester): [Mcload](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/72137/mcload)

## **North America**

Canada

- Montreal: [blackbird](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/9551/blackbird)
- Vancouver: [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx)
- Toronto: [Eugene O](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13320/eugene-o)
- Regina, Saskatchewan: [Jim MacKenzie](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62876/jim-mackenzie)

Mexico

- Tijuana: [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo) (see also San Diego)
- Playas de Rosarito: [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo)

USA

- [Baltimore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltimore), MD: [Sheik Paul](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/56513/sheik-paul)
- New York, NJ, PA: [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson)
- [Mid-Atlantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Atlantic_states) States: [choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster)
- Tampa, Los Angeles - [VMAtm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19/vmatm)
- Seattle, WA - [Azor-Ahai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32836/azor-ahai), [JonathanReez](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez)
- Portland, OR - [Mikey](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey)
- Denver, CO - [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas)
- San Diego: [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo) (see also Tijuana/Playas de Rosarito)
- Lane County, OR: [Groleau](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau)

## **Oceania**

Australia

- Melbourne: [Tim Malone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10264/tim-malone)

New Zealand

- Christchurch: [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill)

## **South America**

Perú

- Lima: [Washu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4605/washu)

Ecuador

- Quito: [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)

## **The Middle East**

Kuwait

- [Burhan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid); also for Dubai and Bahrain (on occasion).

Iran

- Hamadan: [azerafati](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/33240/azerafati)

Comment: I'm somewhat ambivalent about this. I see two things wrong here - a. I don't know if the people concerned are ok with it or not b. How do you trust strangers  when many of them do not even have their photo on travel SE.  A meeting on meetup.com or something similar could be a game-changer of course. something which is similar to tripadvisor as well perhaps.

Comment: @shirish many of us have met up already and it's been great.  Meet in a public place and be safe :)

Comment: If you don't trust, you don't put your name in it.  Why don't you know if I'm OK with it?  If I weren't, you wouldn't see my name.  Of course I will make an individual decision should someone ask to meet.

Comment: @Gagravarr I've edited this to clean up the list of people "near London". If I misinterpreted either of your intentions with regards to your willingness to meet actually in London, feel free to edit it to better reflect :)

Comment: @Aleks-G See above comment

Comment: @Muzer no problem.

Comment: Is it possible to make this question and answer only readable by people who have joined Travel.SE?  Hopefully we’re all sufficiently civilized to not put someone else’s name in.  (I don’t remember putting myself in it, but I need to either change it now to the correct location or remove it.