# Buddy up/looking for travel companions questions

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this has been addressed (can't find it via search) but are "looking for travel buddy" type questions appropriate here? Gut instinct is to take this kind of thing to the chat, but this is not visible or searchable and much less permanent. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chat is searchable FYI (top right of the chat window).

However, we have suggested [this post for finding other Travel.SE members](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/meet-other-travel-se-members).

However, as the Travel.SE site is a Q&A site for specific questions, polling for people to travel with probably isn't going to be on topic, unfortunately. Best bet is probably the linked thread, or the chat, and let us know where you'll be.

Comment: I should clarify, the chat is not something that would pop up when searching by search engine like Google or Bing, and given that there's not many people in chat or even aware of it, it is improbable (but not impossible) to have success with. Thanks for the pointer to the meet-up thread.

Comment: @DarkoZ ah true, I see what you mean.  Do pop in and let us know your plans tho!